# Comodo certificate , signing VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net, certificate, clickonce

I have *.p7s certificate purchased from Comodo 
that should be used to sign VB.NET desktop application.
When I open that file with IE it shows few certificates inside file and 
I can successfully import that into the store.

What are steps required to sign my application that is deployed through ClickOnce ?

EDIT: If I go to IE - Tools- Content - Certificates I see my cert listed.
Only export format I get is *.cer and *.p7b

Which should I choose ?

Comment: MSDN is your friend :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/che5h906%28v=vs.80%29.aspx I guess you have to convert the certificate to the right format. I'm not sure if the signing process can use the `p7b` format directly.